# While loop not working in Python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

The while loop is not working properly. The again variable will dictate whether or not the while loop will be executed again. If again = 1, then the while loop will be executed and the program will run again. If again =0, then it will not.

For some reason, again=1 always, so no matter what, while loop is always being executed. Does anyone notice an error in the code?

```
 score = 0
 loops = 0
 again = 1
 while (again != 0):
    import random
    real = random.randint(1,9)
    fake1 = random.randint(1,9)
    fake2 = random.randint(1,9)
    comb = random.randint(1,9)
    rep = 0
    guess = 0

    if (comb == 1 or comb == 2 or comb == 3):
        print(real, fake1, fake2)
        loops += 1
        guess = int(input("Choose between these numbers"))
        if (guess == real):
            score += 1
            print ("Congrats!")
        else:
            print ("Wrong, better luck next time!")
    if (comb == 4 or comb == 5 or comb == 6):
        print (fake1, fake2, real)
        loops += 1
        guess = int(input("Choose between these numbers"))
        if (guess == real):
            score += 1
            print ("Congrats!")
        else:
            print ("Wrong, better luck next time!")

    if (comb == 7 or comb == 8 or comb == 9):
        print (fake2, real, fake1)
        loops += 1
        guess = int(input("Choose between these numbers"))
        if (guess == real):
            score += 1
            print ("Congrats!")
        else:
            print ("Wrong, better luck next time!")
    again == int(input("Do you wanna go again?"))
    print(again)
```

Comment: `again == ` isn't assignment, it's checking for equality.

Answer (score 1):

You use a comparison operator while assigning a value into variable called **again** :

```
again == int(input("Do you wanna go again?"))
```

You must delete one of the equals signs:

```
again = int(input("Do you wanna go again?"))
```

Comment: I feel dumb, such an easy fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
again == int(input("Do you wanna go again?"))
```

This is not going to do what you think, because == means it is checking if this statement is true. You want to have a single =.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't see this. Such a simple fix! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For this line:

```
again == int(input("Do you wanna go again?"))
```

The ‘==‘ is what you use for returning a Boolean of either True or false when comparing two values. For example:

```
print(2 > 1)
# output: True
```

The code should be corrected to:

```
again = int(input("Do you wanna go again?"))
```